# Bar chart is not showing in repl.it

Tags: python, plotly

it and the programming language i am using is Python. When i run this code it does not show me anything. I am expecting to see a bar chart.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Bar(y=[2, 3, 1]))
fig.show()
```

Comment: I don't think online coding IDE's support ploting. Why don't you try in a basic desktop IDE (like jupyter) ?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Repl.it is like and online coding platform but what program would you suggest for me to download to run python that has a nice interface.

Answer (score 0):

This might be late but if anyone is looking for a solution you can use Dash to provide an http server and serve the chart as an html page.
See the example here: https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/#line-charts-in-dash

In your case a simple code would look like this:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Bar(y=[2, 3, 1]))
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id="line-chart", figure=fig),
])
app.run_server(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```